# How to update specific values in XML document with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I recently asked a similar question but had problems with the proposed solution, so am rephrasing it slightly differently with sample code this time.  I have an XML file which stores data for players of a game.  I simply need to find a player periodically from this XML file and update his associated data as the specific player plays the game:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<PlayerStats xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <Player>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <WinCount>3</WinCount>
    <PlayCount>9</PlayCount>
    <Balance>500</Balance>
  </Player>

  <Player>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <WinCount>3</WinCount>
    <PlayCount>9</PlayCount>
    <Balance>940</Balance>
  </Player>

</PlayerStats>
```

I need the code to identify a specific player (example, John) and update the Wincount, Playcount, and Balance numbers based on C# variables.  Here is some sample C# code I am working with:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(xmlfilepath);
    XmlNode player;
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

    // below correctly pulls data for the specific player
    player = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::Player[Name='"+Form1.strPlayerName+"']"); 

   // the "inner xml" for player = "<Name>John</Name><WinCount>3</WinCount><PlayCount>9</PlayCount><Balance>940</Balance>"

    // since "Balance" was last, I tried using "LastChild" and the code below worked
    player.LastChild.InnerText = Form1.decBalance.ToString();  //updates balance succesfully 
    doc.Save(xmlfilepath);
```

So this works for the "LastChild", but how do i change "Wincount", "PlayCount", and "Balance" without referencing them as either first or last?  I got some suggestions before using LINQ and XML serialization, etc., but they caused problems and I do not understand LINQ yet.  I REALLY want to use XmlDocument bc I feel like this code is 95% of the way there and I am missing something easy.  I am new to C# so using as much of the code above would make my life much easier if possible.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do it like this:

```
player["WinCount"].InnerText = Form1.winCount.ToString();
player["PlayCount"].InnerText = Form1.playCount.ToString();
player["Balance"].InnerText = Form1.decBalance.ToString();
```

Documentation [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sss31aas.aspx)

Comment: @overlook77 for your own sanity's sake, you should try using XPath expressions exclusively for doing XML manipulation.  If the XML format changes, it can be very annoying to handle without using XPath (i.e. XPathNavigator)